# Order by case when sort order

Tags: oracle

I apologize if the title isn't accurate to what I am about to ask.  Please make any suggestions to help improve.

I have an SQL code that is pulling in a large list. In this list are a number of items.

```
Items
--------
Apple
Egg
Cheese
Pear
Goat
Bear
Toad
Horse
Log
```

What the client wants is to always have a couple items always on the bottom

```
Items
--------
Apple
Toad
Horse
Log
Egg << always on bottom
Cheese << always on bottom
Pear << always on bottom
Goat << always on bottom
Bear << always on bottom
```

So I put in an order by case clause that looks like this

```
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN item= 'Egg' THEN '1'
WHEN item= 'Cheese' THEN '1'
WHEN item= 'Pear' THEN '1'
WHEN item= 'Goat' THEN '1'
WHEN item= 'Bear' THEN '1'
ELSE '0' 
END, 
item ASC
```

So any item that isn't the above, is sorted alphabetically and all the other items show up on the bottom.  Well the client came back saying that the ones on the bottom, they want sorted alphabetically too, only still on the bottom.

How would I go about doing that? I tried adding ASC behind END but that didn't seem to do the trick. I also tried different pecking order, like THEN '1', THEN '2', THEN '3' so on and so forth, that didn't do it either.

Comment: Tag properly!!!  Which one are you using??  Oracle or SQL Server???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier to follow if you add "sort-group" to the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT
    item,
    ( CASE
        WHEN item IN ( 'Egg', 'Cheese', 'Pear', 'Goat', 'Bear' )
            THEN 1
        ELSE
            0
    END ) AS sortGroup,
    otherColumns...
FROM
    table
ORDER BY
    sortGroup,
    item
```

I made a SQLfiddle (targeting MySQL, but the same SQL works on SQL Server and Oracle): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23cebd/3

Here are the results I get:

```
item    sortGroup
Apple   0
Horse   0
Log     0
Toad    0
Bear    1
Cheese  1
Egg     1 
Goat    1
Pear    1
```

This would match your client's requirements:

> Well the client came back saying that the ones on the bottom, they want sorted alphabetically too, only still on the bottom.

Comment: So I tried this option, and I got it to sort the values to the bottom like it should but it doesn't sort them still. They are on the bottom like they should be, but in the wrong order.

Comment: @CheezStix I saw you accepted my answer - is it working for you now?

Answer (score 1):

Your ORDER BY was close to what you're up to.

```
SQL> with test (item) as
  2  (select 'apple'  from dual union
  3   select 'egg'    from dual union
  4   select 'cheese' from dual union
  5   select 'pear'   from dual union
  6   select 'goat'   from dual union
  7   select 'bear'   from dual union
  8   select 'toad'   from dual union
  9   select 'horse'  from dual union
 10   select 'log'    from dual
 11  )
 12  select item
 13  from test
 14  order by case when item in ('egg', 'cheese', 'pear', 'goat', 'bear') then '1'
 15                else '0'
 16           end,
 17           item;

ITEM
------
apple
horse
log
toad
bear
cheese
egg
goat
pear

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: So I changed my Order by clause to look like this:

ORDER BY 
   CASE
      WHEN item IN ('egg','cheese','pear','goat','bear')
      THEN '1'
      ELSE '0'
   END,
filing_status ASC;

and it's still not sorting as it should

Comment: To me, it looks OK, i.e. sample data you provided is sorted correctly. What's wrong?